# Does chrome removes extensions at update?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Does google chrome removes the current extensions when it updates itself to newer version?

i was have an extension at webstore Google has removed it because of i was used a picture that's registered by another company with any notice

i lost my all users. when google chrome has updated itself does it removes all extensions? or just check if still exists in store or not?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Chrome checks if any extensions have been removed from the Web Store, and if so, removes those applications from the user's browser. Update time would be a reasonable place to do such a check, but it may run the check other times, too, like at startup.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had Chrome remove my extensions when I updated.